# How to make botton stay in bottom of screen

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, dialog

i have botton inner of `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, i want botton always stay in bottom of screen when bottomSheet slide up / or drag, button not appear only when BottomSheet dismiss, this is layout of bottomSheetDialog

```
     <FrameLayout>

        <!--content-->
        <LinearLayout

            <!--header-->
            <LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout>

            <!--BOTTON-->
            <Botton/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

but button always in bottom of layout bottomSheet, not in bottom of screen.

how to keep it under the screen

i want create like comment line, but ui comment is button and i'm using buttonSheetDialog

[image]

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your ui?

Comment: @MaxAves i have update my question

Comment: honestly, I am not getting the point what is the problem, could you show difference on screenshot?

Comment: @MaxAves this is the ui
https://pasteboard.co/HueLnWD.jpg
https://pasteboard.co/HueLJdx.jpg

Comment: So you problem is that you button is always on bottom even when dialog is not open fully?

Comment: yes, i want button always in bottom of screen, when dialog open full or not @MaxAves